# Prelude dhall Error: Connection establishment took too long

Tags: yaml, dhall, haskell-prelude

Today my dhall project has started crashing on Prelude dependencies, so the main error is:

```
Error: Connection establishment took too long.
```

I use this deps:

```
let List/map = https://prelude.dhall-lang.org/List/map

let Map/values = https://prelude.dhall-lang.org/Map/values

let Text/concatSep = https://prelude.dhall-lang.org/Text/concatSep
```

and when I tried to generate a yaml file: `dhall-to-yaml`
, this message appears:

```
Error: Connection establishment took too long

URL: https://prelude.dhall-lang.org/List/map
```

any help ??

Comment: This is probably related to https://github.com/dhall-lang/dhall-lang/issues/1268. dhall-lang.org is up again now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I had to temporarily disable IPv6 on dhall-lang.org.  I later re-enabled IPv6, which fixed this problem.  For more details, see: https://github.com/dhall-lang/dhall-lang/issues/1268